# Gitlab docker image can't reach smtp ports of my mailserver

Tags: docker, email, gitlab

I have a gitlab_ce instance running on-premise, version 16.9.2.

Gitlab can't deliver EMails via our mail server. I'm pretty sure that this has worked in the past. This is my config:

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "mail.mycompany.de"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 465
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "mycompany.de"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = 'username'                      
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = 'passwd'  
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = false
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_ssl'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_pool'] = false
gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'none'

gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_enabled'] = true
```

Since gitlab is not the only piece of software using this mail server, I'm sure that the settings are correct. Authentication shouldn't be necessary.
I added these settings to try them out at least once. All recipients have a mailbox managed by this server.

Now, with these settings I opened a console to send mail:

```
Notify.test_email('my.name@mycompany.de', 'Message Subject', 'Message Body').deliver_now
Delivered mail 65f95c1432f38_374d32d009195e@gitlab.mycompany.de.mail (30043.0ms)
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/net-smtp-0.3.3/lib/net/smtp.rb:645:in `rescue in tcp_socket': Timeout to open TCP connection to mail.mycompany.de:465 (exceeds 30 seconds) (Net::OpenTimeout)
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:61:in `connect_internal': Connection timed out - user specified timeout (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
```

I pinged the mail server from inside the container and the ping returns an echo. -> ping and dns works

I tried to connect to the port 465 and didn't get an answer (timeout).

```
openssl s_client -connect mail.mycompany.de:465 -crlf
```

If I try connection on the host I get an answer.

Even curl works from inside the container, e.g.

```
curl https://www.google.de
```

This is how I start the container:

```
docker run --detach \
  --hostname gitlab.mycompany.de \
  -p 127.0.0.1:8443:443 \
  --name gitlab \
  --restart unless-stopped \
  --volume /var/www/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
  --volume /var/www/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
  --volume /var/www/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
  --network plantuml-n \
  --shm-size 256m \
  gitlab/gitlab-ce:$1
```

where `$1` is the version I want to start. As you can see, I use a network for plantuml which has the name plantuml-n. I created the network before the first installation:

```
docker network create plantuml-n
```

This is a bridged network, which should be OK for outgoing traffic.

Do you have any ideas about the cause of blocking the outgoing traffic from inside the container?

**tcpdump**

The container got the address 172.19.0.2 from docker. The following entries appear, opening the dump in wireshark (the mailserver address is a.b.c.d):

```
1   0.000000    172.19.0.2  a.b.c.d TCP 74  48448 → 465 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1327671969 TSecr=0 WS=128
2   1.019036    172.19.0.2  a.b.c.d TCP 74  [TCP Retransmission] 48448 → 465 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1327672988 TSecr=0 WS=128
... repeated TCP Retransmissions
```

On the host I sniffed the br-xxxxxxxx device for the plantuml-n network and can see the outgoing SYN and retransmissions.

On the host I sniffed the br-xxxxxxxx device for the container hosting the mail server. I can't see the SYN and retransmission packages there.

I can't see the SYN package in the container where the mail server resides.

**The following data were requested in the comments:**

**OS Container AND Host:**

Ubuntu 22.04

**Firewall**

Container: None

Host: ufw

**`iptables-save`**

Container:

```
iptables-save: command not found
```

Host

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [433787:20575608]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [21:888]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [6098:480927]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
:ufw-after-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-input - [0:0]1
:ufw-after-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-after-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-allow - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-deny - [0:0]
:ufw-not-local - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-input - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-output - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-input - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-output - [0:0]
:ufw-track-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-track-input - [0:0]
:ufw-track-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit-accept - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-output - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o br-79dd7e626a8f -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-79dd7e626a8f -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-79dd7e626a8f ! -o br-79dd7e626a8f -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-79dd7e626a8f -o br-79dd7e626a8f -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-5d7297ff3a1b -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-5d7297ff3a1b -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-5d7297ff3a1b ! -o br-5d7297ff3a1b -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-5d7297ff3a1b -o br-5d7297ff3a1b -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-260e4a48fccf -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-260e4a48fccf -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-260e4a48fccf ! -o br-260e4a48fccf -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-260e4a48fccf -o br-260e4a48fccf -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-5d7297ff3a1b -o br-5d7297ff3a1b -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.3/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8081 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.21.0.2/32 ! -i br-79dd7e626a8f -o br-79dd7e626a8f -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.21.0.2/32 ! -i br-79dd7e626a8f -o br-79dd7e626a8f -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.21.0.2/32 ! -i br-79dd7e626a8f -o br-79dd7e626a8f -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.21.0.2/32 ! -i br-79dd7e626a8f -o br-79dd7e626a8f -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.21.0.2/32 ! -i br-79dd7e626a8f -o br-79dd7e626a8f -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.21.0.2/32 ! -i br-79dd7e626a8f -o br-79dd7e626a8f -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.3/32 ! -i br-5d7297ff3a1b -o br-5d7297ff3a1b -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-79dd7e626a8f ! -o br-79dd7e626a8f -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-260e4a48fccf ! -o br-260e4a48fccf -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-5d7297ff3a1b ! -o br-5d7297ff3a1b -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-79dd7e626a8f -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-260e4a48fccf -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-5d7297ff3a1b -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -d 10.0.0.0/8 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j DROP
-A DOCKER-USER -d 10.0.0.0/8 -p udp -m udp --dport 0:32767 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-logging-input -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -j ufw-user-forward
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -m udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local
-A ufw-before-input -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -d 239.255.255.250/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-user-input
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -j ufw-user-output
-A ufw-logging-allow -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
-A ufw-logging-deny -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j RETURN
-A ufw-logging-deny -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-forward -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-input -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-output -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-forward -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-forward -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m comment --comment "\'dapp_Nginx%20Full\'" -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -s 172.17.0.0/16 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 51821 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -s 10.8.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3333 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -s 10.8.1.0/25 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -s 10.8.1.0/25 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1433 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -s 10.8.1.0/25 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -s 10.8.1.0/25 -p udp -m udp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-limit -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
-A ufw-user-limit -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Mar 20 08:31:48 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Wed Mar 20 08:31:48 2024
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.21.0.0/16 ! -o br-79dd7e626a8f -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.0/16 ! -o br-5d7297ff3a1b -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.0/16 ! -o br-260e4a48fccf -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.2/32 -d 172.17.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.3/32 -d 172.17.0.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8081 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.21.0.2/32 -d 172.21.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.21.0.2/32 -d 172.21.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.21.0.2/32 -d 172.21.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.21.0.2/32 -d 172.21.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.21.0.2/32 -d 172.21.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.21.0.2/32 -d 172.21.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.3/32 -d 172.19.0.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i br-79dd7e626a8f -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i br-260e4a48fccf -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i br-5d7297ff3a1b -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -d 127.0.0.1/32 ! -i br-5d7297ff3a1b -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:8080
-A DOCKER -d 127.0.0.1/32 ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3001 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:3000
-A DOCKER -d 127.0.0.1/32 ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5006 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.3:8081
-A DOCKER ! -i br-79dd7e626a8f -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.21.0.2:995
-A DOCKER ! -i br-79dd7e626a8f -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.21.0.2:993
-A DOCKER ! -i br-79dd7e626a8f -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.21.0.2:587
-A DOCKER ! -i br-79dd7e626a8f -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.21.0.2:465
-A DOCKER ! -i br-79dd7e626a8f -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.21.0.2:143
-A DOCKER ! -i br-79dd7e626a8f -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.21.0.2:25
-A DOCKER -d 127.0.0.1/32 ! -i br-5d7297ff3a1b -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.3:443
COMMIT
```

**`ip route list`**

Container

```
172.19.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link  src 172.19.0.3
```

Host

```
default via a.b.c.d dev enp0s31f6 proto static onlink
10.8.1.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.1.1
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-260e4a48fccf proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-5d7297ff3a1b proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1
172.21.0.0/16 dev br-79dd7e626a8f proto kernel scope link src 172.21.0.1
```

Comment: Port 465 would usually not accept Telnet connections, and reject the attempt to handshake because the client does not speak TLS. The immediate explanation would seem to be that a firewall might be blocking port 465.

Comment: @tripleee: Thanks for your answer. I can telnet to port 465 from outside the container. I can't do anything useful on the connection, but it is enough to prove that a connection is possible. Gitlab resides in a docker container and from there a connection is not possible. I tried to check ufw status inside the container, but ufw is not installed. Is there way to check, if another fw is installed in the container?

Comment: Also checked the following: 

root@gitlab:/# firewall-cmd --state

bash: firewall-cmd: command not found

root@gitlab:/# iptables -L -v

bash: iptables: command not found

Comment: Depends on where you got the container, of course, but that seems unlikely. If it's not a firewall then maybe something in how the Docker container's network is configured.

Comment: Please check the connection from within the container using `openssl s_client -connect mail.mycompany.de:465 -crlf` (in case the port were 587, then you should add the parameter `-starttls smtp`) and send `HELO tests` for testing purposes. Please refrain from using telnet for this purpose.

Comment: What operating system does the host machine of the container have? Is there any firewall between your machine and your company's mail server? Depending on the host operating system, the method to enable traffic would vary. What type of containers are you using? Additionally, have you also tried connecting from the host machine directly? It would be important to rule out whether the host can connect and the container cannot.

Comment: @OscarGarcia: That's what I wrote. I can connect from the host but not from the container.

Comment: @tripleee: I added the container configuration in my question. The container uses a bridged network which was created beforehand.

Comment: @OscarGarcia: I tried your openssl code from the host, it works. From the container: doesn't work (timeout). OS both host and container: Ubuntu 22.4, no firewall between host and mail server.

Comment: This is very tangentially programming-related anyway. Can you connect to port 465 on other external servers?

Comment: @tripleee Yes, connection from other external servers is possible. Even from other containers on the same host.

Comment: Well, it seems, that the one container with `--network host` can connect to the server on port 465, the others with bridged network cannot connect. curl works. This is weird.

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate https://superuser.com/questions/1745422/docker-containers-cannot-reach-internet-in-bridge-network-mode

Comment: I'm sorry, using the 'telnet' command didn't fully clarify it for me. Please, visit the question that has been proposed to you. There might be a routing conflict. If not, please provide the operating systems as I requested to check the firewall rules. Generally, `iptables-save` does the job well, and you can check the routes with `ip route list`. Thank you.

Comment: PS: Please, share only the firewall rules and the routing table. I read in the second comment the operating system. You should add that information to the question to make it visible and easier for people who come across this thread to offer their assistance.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Thanks a lot for your comments. I added the requested data in the question.

Comment: @tripleee: I watched the superuser post you mentioned. The difference is, that the TO can't ping to the internet, while I can from the container. Even curl works and get's an answer from a https site.

Answer (score 0):

```
> "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/net-smtp-0.3.3/lib/net/smtp.rb:645:in
> `rescue in tcp_socket': Timeout to open TCP connection to
> mail.mycompany.de:465 (exceeds 30 seconds) (Net::OpenTimeout)
> /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:61:in
> `connect_internal': Connection timed out - user specified timeout
> (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
```

I'd suggest to check with tcpdump on both sender and receiver whether actually traffic is received. Since it says that tcp connection timed out. And you said the ping works. That means that either nothing is send out, nothing is received, or the TCP connection is simply reject/dropped.
With that information it might help to find out where it issue is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added my findings in the question. I see SYN packages in the container, but no ACK. I can't see the SYN package at the host and not in the container with the mailserver. The route should be container->host->host->container. It seems as if the SYN package doesn't leave the host.